# Close Excel file after a SaveCopyAs was created on desktop

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA:

```
Sub Create_Sent_File()
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & "Sent_File" & ".xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

The code creates a new file called `"Sent_File"` on the desktop of the user.

All this works fine so far.

---

However, after the file is created I want to close the original Excel file. 
**The exact same way I would do it if I have three Excel files open and then I close one of them.**

Therefore, I tried to go with this formula:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Now, the issue is that the workbook is closed but Excel somehow remains open:

[image]

What do I need to change in my code so: 
a) The current workbook in which I run the VBA is closed. 
b) Other workbooks in Excel remain open. 
c) Excel does not stay open as seen in the screenshot.

Comment: Side note: `"C:\Users\" & Environ("Username")` - you can use `Environ("Userprofile")`.

Comment: Where are you running the code from?

Comment: I run it from the modul

Comment: Try something along these lines after the workbook close `if workbooks.count=0 then application.quit`

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, but you need a reference to the parent application before you then trigger its closure.

```
Sub Create_Sent_File()
    Dim xlParent As Excel.Application

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\" & "Sent_File" & ".xlsm"
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = False

    Set xlParent = ActiveWorkbook.Parent
    xlParent.Quit
End Sub
```

Having set the `Saved` flag for the current workbook to `False` you can close the host Excel app without triggering any confirmation boxes.

If you have other workbooks open that you also want to close without confirmation, you'll need to work through the `Workbooks` collection, setting the `Saved` property of each to `False` before then proceeding with quitting the host Excel app.